# Execute multiple PHP Scripts in the Background

Tags: php, background, laravel, gearman, worker

I'm writing a web application that needs to execute PHP scripts in the background. The problem with queues is that it can only process one at a time. My question is, how can I let Beanstalk process more jobs at the same time or how can I execute my script in the background which would be going on till the user stopped it manually. I'm using Laravel 4 so I have all those methods at my disposal.

Thanks in advance.

The API couldn't help me either btw.

```
<?php

class Workers {

    public function fire($job, $data) {
        $login = Login::find($data['id']);
        if ($login->active == 0) {
            $job->delete();
        }

        $job->release();
    }
}
```

This is what my script looks like currently. Note the `release()` instead of `delete()`. This is so it keeps executing.

I did some research again and found out that a Background Worker may be something for me. Could anyone link me to a tutorial on how to set those up on Linux and what my options are regarding Background worker software. Beanstalk doesn't seem to offer that option.

I just found out that http://gearman.org/ could be a possibility but I'm not sure since I don't know very much about workers. I also found this http://kvz.io/blog/2009/01/09/create-daemons-in-php/ which looks like it could do the job.

Is it possible to have a unique worker for every time the script needs to be run? A complete new instance? If so, how and using which program / platform?

I would like to personally thank the guy(s) that help me get out my nightmare. I have gazillion of people shouting at me when the app is finally finished. Appreciated, a lot!

Comment: You need to me more specific, tell us what you're trying to do, show some code, so we can help you.

Comment: It can go anywhere, see [PSR-0 autoloading](http://www.sitepoint.com/autoloading-and-the-psr-0-standard/). Likely you want to [create your own application library](http://fideloper.com/laravel-4-application-setup-app-library-autoloading) to house your application logic.

Comment: I edited the question to make it more clear and precise. `put on hold as too broad`

Comment: I hope it is clear to everyone?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I implemented a solution for PHP deamons about 2.5 years ago. My application runs in a closed environment and has only a few users. So scalability, performance and security was not really required.

I basically started my deamons as single PHP applications in CLI mode.

```
function startDeamon($daemonPath, $args = ""){
    $phppath = "/../../php/php"; // points to php executable
    $executionstring = $phppath." -f ".$daemonPath." ".$args;
    execInBackground($executionstring);
}

function execInBackground($cmd){
    if (substr(php_uname(), 0, 7) == "Windows"){
        pclose(popen("start /B". $cmd, "r")); // Windows
    } else {
        exec($cmd . " > /dev/null &"); // Operating systems like unix
    }
}
```

By calling `startDaemon` with the path to your daemon script and the arguments you want to give it, a separate process is started on your web server. The process ends as soon as the daemon script terminates.

The arguments can be read in your daemon by accessing the `$argv` array like so:

```
 $myJobIs = $argv[1];
```

Keep in mind that this solution is very intensive on memory since every started process can take up like 5MB of RAM or more. (But it depends on your PHP installation, your system and your script)

And you also need to allow PHP to open new processes / run the exec function which might not be something you want to do.